# Check correctness of the algorithm for minimum number of jumps in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I have an algorithm that is based on a problem where you need to find the minimum number of jumps to reach the end of the array.This problem was asked in geeks for geeks and they do not have a linear time algorithm in my case the algorithm is in linear time but **for which test case would my Algorithm fail?**.The link for the problem

Link:-http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-jumps-to-reach-end-of-a-given-array/

Input: arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 2, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9}

- Starting from the first element we know that the maximum range of the element is 1 hence we can move only one step forward so from 1->3
- Now in the second step we know the range of the element is 3 hence from that step we calculate the max from that range so from 3 we can either chose 5,8,9 and the maximum in this range is 9
- So first move to 9 that is 1->3->9 and then from 9 we move towards the end of the array as we know that nine steps are more than enough to reach the end.
- Corner case is that if we detect a zero at the end we do nothing as we have already reached the end.But if a zero is detected at the start or in a range where 0 is the maximum element in that range to move forward we return a -1 as we cannot move further **please tell me if there is a bug in this algorithm.**

Comment: The expectation on SO is that you would attempt to solve the problem (including {pseudo}code) and we would attempt to help you if it failed. Our 'task' is not to debug for you before you do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this algorithm does not work. Example:

```
arr[] = {5,2,1,1,1,1,1}
```

Your algorithm would see 5, then see max number 2, then go to 1 1 1 1. That is:
5,2,1,1,1,1 = 6 jumps.

While the optimal result is: 5 -> 1 (second from end) -> 1 = 3 jumps